# css problem-liqiud layout-cannot use height in pixels-min height not working

Tags: css-float, css

As I am designing a liquid layout all my width and height are in %. but while designing I have to see whats going on with my css so I gave height in pixels (temporarily) as that height (in %) will be filled from data from database.presently no database is designed. I cannot use pixels so i tried min-height property to see my css result.. but thats also not working.What sholud i do?

Comment: Do you have some source code or a live example we can take a look at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a % height, the height is calculated in relation to its parent container. This often trips people up as the following cannot reasonably be calculated:

```
<body>
    <div style="height: 100%;">Hello World</div>
</body>
```

We are asking the browser to render the div at "100%" - but the browser cannot apply this style as the body has no explicit height.

To fix this, you need to give a height to the html and body, like this...

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This now gives the div a height to work to - which will essentially equate to the size of the view port.

This applies to height and min-height.